# Regex pattern to detect anything like $$_$$

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex that works like below if I have something like

```
Hi $$var1$$ $$var2$$ how are you?
```

it should return me two  matches

```
$$var1$$ -1st match

$$var2$$ -2nd match
```

Currently i have made a regex `/\$\$\w+\d*\W*\$\$/gi` this works fine if the two patterns are not next to each other for eg:

```
Hi $$var1$$ and $$var2$$ how are you?
```

it detects two matches, but if these two matches are next to each other like in the first example seperated by space it detects `$$var1$$  $$`. Can someone help me fix this regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \$\$\w+\d*?\W*?\$\$
              ^^
```

Make your `\W` non greedy as it will eat up `$$ $$` but not `$$ and $$` as it cannot consume `and`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tP7qE7/5

Answer (score 3):

I don't know all your restrictions, but it might be easier and faster with a negated class:

```
\$\$[^$]+\$\$
```

If single dollar signs are allowed between the double ones, then you might use something like this to keep up the same speed:

```
\$\$(?:[^$]+|\$(?!\$))+\$\$
```

`(?:[^$]+|\$(?!\$))+` matches either a non `$` or one `$` that is not followed by a second `$` (though at that point, `\$\$.+?\$\$` would actually be simpler should that be the case).

The reason why your regex was not behaving as you expected was that `\W*` can potentially match any dollar signs. So if there was anything that does not match `\w` in between the last dollar signs of pattern you want to match, your regex would continue matching until the next double dollar signs.